# Objectify error despite all the instructions

Tags: eclipse, gwt, objectify

I get this ...[ERROR] Unable to find 'com/googlecode/objectify/Objectify.gwt.xml'...
When I am trying to run the GWT application using objectify.

The app itself runs, up until I insert 
  
then it gives me error

*Loading inherited module 'com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify'
            [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/googlecode/objectify/Objectify.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?*

I have no idea how to solve this. I did the external lib add path, import into war/WEB-INF/lib folder (objectify-4.0b1-javadoc.jar)

This is all using Eclipse

The environment is 1.6

Comment: Added jar to class path ??

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the -javadoc.jar file in WEB-INF/lib, put the normal objectify jar there.